# WP URL Rewrites/Custom Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to set custom URL's for my WP posts across 2 domains using WPML. I had been hoping the Custom Permalinks plugin would be able to do this, but after investigation, it does not work well with WPML.

Is there any way I can do this? With HTAccess rewrites perhaps?

How the site currently looks (WP standard permalinks with horrible numbers if the post name is the same!):

- http://example.com/first-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.com/second-location/introductory-dive-2
- http://example.com/third-location/introductory-dive-3
- http://example.de/first-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.de/second-location/introductory-dive-2
- http://example.de/third-location/introductory-dive-3

How I want it to look (clean and without numbers):

- http://example.com/first-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.com/second-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.com/third-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.de/first-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.de/second-location/introductory-dive
- http://example.de/third-location/introductory-dive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been fixed using Custom Permalinks plugin and some hacks. If you have the same issue, please contact me for the hacked plugin.